# C++ access to on-line file storage

Tags: php, c++, web-services, client-server

I am looking to add to an existing C++/Windows application the on-line storage of application files, for backup purposes and easy of application file access between multiple computers.  The files are around 100k in size, and I’d estimate that each customer will want to store 1-10 of these files, but some may wish to store hundreds in different folders.  I would estimate that over time several thousand customers would want to use this feature, but the average use per month would not be that high (my customers tend to use the software extensively for a couple of months and then settle to a much lower usage pattern).

The security requirements are not high (no personal or sensitive information is in the application files), but basic login authentication would have to take place.  I have a user forum (phpbb), which may be the easiest place to take care of the login creation / password recovery (depending on the server used below).

I have a web server (with php & mysql), and the disk space / bandwidth should not be a problem.  I do not wish to use 3rd party libraries without source, as past experience has shown this introduces bugs / problems upgrading compilers etc.

I’m aware that I’ll need both server and client software and they will need to communicate using a protocol.  As far as I can tell, my options are:

- Use an existing online storage provider, such as DropBox.  The problem I see with this is the client side interface software (I know of SharpBox, but it is .net), and other possible restrictions on storage space, account activity etc.
- Use open source online storage software, such as OwnCloud. WebDAV should be able to be used for the interface, but again there currently is no client software for OwnCloud. I did get as far as setting up OwnCloud 2 and 3, but WebDAV  seemed to only be partically supported.  This is my preferred solution – use an off the shelf server with decent example C++ client to get me started.
- Create my own server, protocol and client front end. I could use WebDAV or SOAP for the protocol.  This is my last option just because of the amount of work to re-invent the wheel, but gives the simplest, most flexible system and best chance of integration with the phpbb forum for login credentials etc.

Are there other options which meet my needs which I have overlooked?

Comment: How about ftp uploads (Windows has a nice built-in FTP API - WinInet) and a simple php script to handle the files uploaded?

Comment: I guess that would be in the last (custom) category.  I believe that FTP would require a daemon running on the server.  Main disadvantage I can think of is the login handling.

Comment: Here's a follow up, one year on.  I used mysql for the database, php for the back end, html/xml for the transport, and used windows sockets on the client.  It ended being fairly simple and I got a prototype system going in only a day or two, and then spent another couple of weeks finishing it off.